# Angular and ExtJS Co-existence

Tags: angular, extjs

Can a single application support both Angular and ExtJS co-existing?  I am aware of ExtAngular but I'm not wanting to go there.

Comment: Theoretically yes. Just create a div with some ID and render your extjs app into that div. If you will need controll extjs components from angular, you will have to go there.

Comment: Thanks for the response Arthur.  This sounds like an approach to injecting an ExtJS component into an Angular app?  Would you say anything different for injecting an Angular component into an ExtJS app?  This is my use case.

Comment: I don`t know what will happen, THEORETICALLY ExtJs component can be rendered in any div using renderTo: ID_OF_THE_ELEMENT. But I would never do it to avoid problems in the future. Angular is using templates, so it is better to inject ExtJs in angular instead of vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting an angular component in to an EXT JS framework is very much possible. There could be more than one way but the way I know to achieve this is using Iframe.

Running by the details -

1. You need to have two separate builds. One is EXT and other is Angular.
2. Create a Iframe component of EXT JS as in below snippet.
3. In src tag - Give angular component url.

   {
   xtype: "component",
   height: 999,
   width: "100%",
   border: 0,
   autoEl: {
   tag: "iframe",
   src: ''
   }
   }